# Chaining async await calls in Node/Express with an external time limit

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, slack-api, knex.js

I'm building a Slackbot that makes a call to an Express app, which then needs to 1) fetch some other data from the Slack API, and 2) insert resulting data in my database. I think I have the flow right finally using `async await`, but the operation is timing out because the original call from the Slackbot needs to receive a response within some fixed time I can't control. It would be fine for my purposes to ping the bot with a response immediately, and then execute the rest of the logic asynchronously. But I'm wondering the best way to set this up.

My Express route looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const knex = require('../../db/knex.js');

const slack = require('../../services/slack_helpers');

// POST api/slack/foo
router.post('/foo', async (req, res) => {
    let [body, images] = await slack.grab_context(req);
    knex('texts')
        .insert({ body: body,
                  image_ids: images })
        .then(text => { res.send('worked!'); }) // This sends a response back to the original Slackbot call
        .catch(err => { res.send(err); })
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then the `slack_helpers` module looks like:

```
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const Slack = new WebClient(process.env.SLACKBOT_TOKEN);

async function grab_context(req) {

    try {
        const context = await Slack.conversations.history({ // This is the part that takes too long
            channel: req.body.channel_id,
            latest: req.headers['X-Slack-Request-Timestamp'],
            inclusive: true,
            limit: 5
        });

    } catch (error) {
        return [error.toString(), 'error'];
    }
    return await parse_context(context);
};

function parse_context(context) {
    var body = [];

    context.messages.forEach(message => {
        body.push(message.text);
    });

    body = body.join(' \n');

    return [body, ''];
}

module.exports = {
    grab_context
};
```

I'm still getting my head around asynchronous programming, so I may be missing something obvious. I think basically something like `res.send` perhaps needs to come before the `grab_context` call? But again, not sure the best flow here.

**Update**

I've also tried this pattern in the API route, but still getting a timeout:

```
slack.grab_context(req).then((body, images) => {
        knex ...
})
```

Comment: Does slackbot support websockets? I assume you still need to get the data back to the slackbot at some point, so a polling mechanism would have to be implemented if you plan to respond immediately, whereas you could just push the message to the slackbot at any point with websockets.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I'm not sure, but I'm actually not sending the data back to Slack -- just to my database. The Slackbot is just the trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timeout may not be coming from where you think. From what I see, it is coming from `grab_context`. Consider the following simplified version of `grab_context`

```js
async function grab_context_simple() {
  try {
    const context = { hello: 'world' }
  } catch (error) {
    return [error.toString(), 'error']
  }
  return context
}
grab_context_simple() /* => Promise {
  <rejected> ReferenceError: context is not defined
  ...
} */
```

You are trying to return `context` outside of the try block where it was defined, so `grab_context` will reject with a `ReferenceError`. It's very likely that this error is being swallowed at the moment, so it would seem like it is timing out.

The fix is to move a single line in `grab_context`

```js
async function grab_context(req) {

    try {
        const context = await Slack.conversations.history({
            channel: req.body.channel_id,
            latest: req.headers['X-Slack-Request-Timestamp'],
            inclusive: true,
            limit: 5
        });

        return await parse_context(context); // <- moved this
    } catch (error) {
        return [error.toString(), 'error'];
    }
};
```

> I'm wondering the best way to set this up.

You could add a higher level `try/catch` block to handle errors that arise from the `/foo` route. You could also improve readability by staying consistent between async/await and promise chains. Below is how you could use async/await with `knex`, as well as the aforementioned `try/catch` block

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const knex = require('../../db/knex.js');

const slack = require('../../services/slack_helpers');

const insertInto = table => payload => knex(table).insert(payload)

const onFooRequest = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let [body, images] = await slack.grab_context(req);
    const text = await insertInto('texts')({
      body: body,
      image_ids: images,
    });
    res.send('worked!');
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
}

router.post('/foo', onFooRequest);

module.exports = router;
```